# Compare two Int32 fields in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, nosql, compare

Hello i am new to MongoDB and hope someone can help me with my problem. I have a collection with the following document structure:

```
    // collection: avgsalarydep
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("60509a82f5034f42e0e0f909"),
    "id" : "zufferli-j",
    "firstname" : "Mark",
    "middlename" : "Clemens ",
    "lastname" : "Zufferli",
    "works_in" : "F",
    "salary" : 50000,
    "email_address" : "addad@enron.com",
    "avgjoin" : [
        {
            "_id" : "F",
            "averagesalary" : 64833
        }
    ]
}
```

Now i simply want to write a find query which shows all the people where their salary is lower than the averagesalary. I tried for example things like:

```
.find({$expr:{$lt:["$salary", "$avgjoin.averagesalary"]}})
```

```
.find({$expr:{$lt:["$salary", "avgjoin.averagesalary"]}})
```

```
{$match:{ $expr: { $lt: { "$salary" , "$avgjoin.averagesalary" } }} }
```

But either it just returns all the people (ignoring if they earn less) or says "No records found". What am i doing wrong? If you need more clarification please feel free to ask. Help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this works:

```
db.avgsalarydep.find({
  $expr: {
    $lt: [
      "$salary",
      {
        $min: "$avgjoin.averagesalary"
      }
    ]
  }
})
```

[Working Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ZRnAKy-9_OV)

I used the [$min](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/min/#mongodb-group-grp.-min) aggregation operator in case there can be more than one document in the `avgjoin` array.

I noticed that in your example document, there's only one element in `avgjoin`, which has the same `_id` as your document's `works_in` field. If this is always the case, updating the document so that there is a single field equivalent to `avgjoin.averagesalary` would allow something like your original attempt to work.